# No Google Play Store in Craig 4.0.3 Android tablet

Tags: google-play-store

I have a Craig 4.0.3 Android tablet.

Can it download apps from the Google Play Store? My tablet does not seem to have the Google Play app.  Is there a way to download the Google Play Store app?

I have already signed up with a Gmail account, which was one of the prerequisites to access the Google Play Store.

Please let me know. I keep getting an error that I cannot download apps, because I don't have the Google Play Store app.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Google Play Store is 3.10.10.

AndroidPolice has hosted an APK which you can [download](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/12/13/download-latest-google-play-store-3-10-10/) and install.

Comment: Keep in mind: When there was no Playstore App previously installed, it's not that easy as simply download the `.apk` and install it. AFAIK Playstore must be a *system app* in order to be able to fully function. So it requires *root* to move the `.apk` to `/system/apps`. Once it's there, updates can be installed normally (that's what your AndroidPolice link is intended for).